# Trying to push the contents of objects nested inside objects to an array (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, nested

When having objects nested inside objects I can't loop through them with a regular for in loop.
I googled and found I have to make a recursive function that would check if the property is an object.
I wrote a recursive function like this:
`

```
 function isObject(value){
        return (typeof(value)==='object');
      }
```

``

```
 function listToArray(list){
        let arr=[];
        for (let elem in list){
            if(isObject(list[elem])===false){
                console.log(list[elem]);
            }
            else if (isObject(list[elem])){
                listToArray(list[elem]);
            }
        }
        return arr;
       }
```

`

this function works well, it loops deeply through all objects nested inside objects and console.logs all properties values. and returns an empty array.

however, when I replace `console.log(list[elem]))` with `arr.push(list[elem])` to make the actual functionality works it pushes only the properties that are not objects in the first bigger object.

This is a coding problem in the book Eloquent JavaScript. I don't want an answer to this problem (in fact the book provides answers) I just want to know why did console.log works and arr.push don't. because it seems so weird to me and I can't find an explanation to that.

Edit:
for Example this object

```
let list = { value : 1,
             rest: { value:2,
                     rest:{value:3,
                           rest:null}
                    }
            }
```

`listToArray(list)` should return [1,2,3]

Comment: Can you describe your problem a bit more clearly?  Do you want all the elements which are not objects to be grouped and pushed into the array?

Comment: I Edited my post and added an Example to show what I meant more clearly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you're not capturing the returned array in your elseif block

```
      function isObject(value){
        return (typeof(value)==='object');
      }
      
       function listToArray(list){
        let arr=[];  
        for (let elem in list){
            if(isObject(list[elem])===false){
                arr.push(list[elem]);
            }
            else if (isObject(list[elem])){
                retArr = listToArray(list[elem]);
                arr = [...arr, ...retArr];
            }
        }
        return arr;
       }
```

Comment: Yes now it seems so obvious. Every time the function makes the recursion the array becomes empty again because of `let arr=[]` at the top. But why is the value pushed the first value though. shouldn't `listToArray(list)' returns [3] instead of [1] ?

Comment: because the first function call to `listToArray`.. it checked two keys `value` and `rest`. `value`(1) is pushed to `arr`.. and for `rest` you did a recursive call with no return so essentially it ignored whatever happened in that and subsequent recursive calls as well. and once all recursive stack is popped.. you just returned the `arr` which has only 1 in it.

Comment: now it is all clear. thank you so much